# How to display values for single attribute across multiple columns in ActiveAdmin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

For a resource page in ActiveAdmin (Rails3 currently), I have a single column display table of a list of values for a single attribute on the resource object, displayed as a string row for each value in the list in view mode and when in edit mode it is a list of checkboxes of a larger collection to select the values. The values are from a single model attribute that is a serialized array stored in the database as a text field.

For `show` handler

```
    show do |company|
     attributes_table do
      ...
      row 'Strategies', :strategy_codes do
        table_for company.strategy_codes do
          column do |code|
            code
          end
        end
      end
      ...
    end
   end
```

For `form` handler

```
  form do |f|
    ...
    f.inputs 'Strategies' do
      f.input :strategy_codes, label: false, as: :check_boxes,
              collection: f.object.available_strategy_codes
              .collect { |l| ["#{l}",l]}.unshift(["Select All"]),
              hint: 'Select the desired strategies',
              input_html: { multiple: true }
    end
    ...
    f.actions
  end
```

Each of the above displays the values for strategy_codes as single column (i.e. 30 or more rows).

In both cases, for show and edit, I would like to organize the values across multiple columns of the table instead of a single column of values because the values list can be 30 items or more and they are short values (5 characters). I would like to be able to specify it be spread across 2, 3, or 4, etc columns so that it is a shorter, but wider, multicolumn display for this one attribute's values.

Is this possible as a modification or addition to ActiveAdmin's view methods?

**Update**

I managed to get the `show` handler working for this "display a list of values across multiple columns" challenge as:

```
  row 'Strategies', :strategy_codes do
    column_count = 4
    row_count = (company.strategy_codes.count / column_count).ceil
    table_for company.strategy_codes.in_groups_of(row_count).transpose do
      (1..row_count).each_with_index do |c,i|
        column do |code|
          code[i]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Since I wanted each column to fill up with rows before moving to the next column, I transposed the array produced by `in_groups_of`.

I haven't had much luck yet however trying to get a collection of checkbox option values for the `form` handler to be displayed across columns in the same manner.

I am wondering if it would be better to try get the client-side to handle this by injecting some css or javascript into the mix.

If I was able to get a `form` `checkboxes` solution working that didn't have the "fill the columns up vertically first" capability and instead filled each row up then moved down to the next row, I would fine with that approach as well.

Ideas?

Comment: did you try to do this? what is your code?

Comment: I haven't tried to split across multiple columns. I added the current code blocks that displays a single column for `show` and `edit`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this using CSS as you considered.

active_admin.scss

```
    form{
        fieldset.inputs{
            ol{
                li.check_boxes{
                    fieldset.choices{
                        ol {
                        -moz-column-count: 4;
                        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
                        -webkit-column-count: 4;
                        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
                        column-count: 4;
                        column-gap: 20px;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```